# What is the impedance value that means it is a low ESR capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, esr

I need to select a 300uF capacitor and it is mentioned in the datasheet that it should be a Low ESR capacitor. However, it is not mentioned the impedance range or how much it should be.

How can I know if the impedance value is low or high ?
If I find a capacitor with 0.5 ohm impedance at 100kHz, is it Low or High ?!

Comment: link to the datasheet, we can't guess the context

Comment: depends on your application. pls share the ref. docs

Answer (score 1):

In general, the impedance of a capacitor with an ESR can be computed as \begin{equation} \dot{Z}_c = ESR - i\frac{1}{\omega C}.\end{equation} Then, knowing the frequency at which the total impedance is given (f = 100 kHz), just solve the equation for ESR.

Usually, values of ESR higher than 0.1 ohm are considered to be "high", but of course that greatly depends on your application.

Comment: What constitutes low/high ESR may also depend on the composition of the capacitor, and the expectations that are associated with it. A "low ESR" electrolytic capacitor may have an ESR that would be considered quite high for a ceramic capacitor.